# Hit a breakpoint when there is certain method in call stack

Tags: .net, debugging, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I want a breakpoint to be hit when there is a certain method in the call stack.
Can I do this somehow with the Visual Studio debugger?

I want to be sure my breakpoint will be hit when the code is called from certain methods, but not others.

For example we have two call stacks:

```
DBReadRecord()
GetRecord()
ActivityMonitor()
```

and

```
DBReadRecord()
GetRecord()
UserButtonDown()
```

I want a breakpoint in `DBReadRecord` to be hit only when it is called from the `UserButtonDown()` method and not from the `ActivityMonitor()` method.

I am using Visual Studio 10 and .Net 3.5.

Comment: Is it a method in your own source or a third party library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do some reflection-based hacking (for example, Express editions seem not to have advanced breakpoint functionalities):

```
    void Foo()
    {
        Foo2();
    }
    void Foo2()
    {
        var trace = new StackTrace();
        if (trace.GetFrames().Reverse().FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetMethod().Name == "Foo") != null)
            Debugger.Break(); // it lives under System.Diagnostics namespace
    }
    void Test()
    {
        Foo2(); // doesn't break here
        Foo(); // break here
    }
```

And with your particular methods:

```
Foo DBReadRecord()
{
     var trace = new StackTrace();
     if (trace.GetFrames().Reverse().FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetMethod().Name == "UserButtonDown") != null)
         Debugger.Break();
}
```

Note that it greatly affects performance, so it's only temporary solution for strange debugging situations.

Also, remember that it works best in `Debug` configurations, I do not know what optimizations may occur that effect in method not being in StackTrace, but such thing can happen when optimizations are turned on.

Comment: This reflection-based hack makes the VS version irrelevant.

Comment: Probably good idea might be to check: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/31799-debugger and possible start new ticket (if nothing similar is posted there already).

Answer (score 1):

**Using Visual Studio**

Go to the Breakpoints window in VS, and click the 'New' button at the top left.

Choose 'Break at Function...' then enter the full name of the method you want to break at (minus its brackets) in the 'Function' field.

E.g. to break on .NET's `Application.Run` method, enter `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run`.

There may be a warning shown that Intellisense cannot find the specified location. This means that you may not be able to see the source code when the breakpoint is hit, but this may still be useful enough for your purposes.

**Using Debugger command**

If you have access to and can compile the source code, you can also use the [`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) command to attach to a debugger programatically while the code is running, or [`Debugger.Break()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) if you are already attached.

Comment: I don't want to break on method. I need to break only when certain method is (deep) in the call stack.

Comment: Ok, I saw your edited question. In that case, you can use @Bartosz's solution to check the call stack, then Debugger.Break() to add the breakpoint.

Comment: Indeed, `Debugger.Break()` seems to be way better idea than my 'no-op' lines that were doing nothing but serving as placeholders for normal VS breakpoints :)